# Ms access pass through query that calls a procedure hangs

Tags: oracle, odbc, ms-access-2016, pass-through

I have a procedure in oracle that runs in about 40 mins when run from oracle.
I have a pass through query in ms access that looks like this

> Begin
> MyProcedure;
> End;

This exact code runs in oracle just fine but hangs in MS access. I don't know if it will finish, it's been going for 6 hours already and I guess it doesn't matter if it finishes or not, this is unacceptable.
Can someone explain what the difference is between running it from oracle and MS access and how I can fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume `MyProcedure` is an Oracle stored procedure.

If that's so, I suggest you include logging into it. How? Create an autonomous transaction procedure (so that it could insert logging information into some *log* table and commit) and call it from `MyProcedure`, for example before every statement it contains (some nasty selects, updates, whatever). Doing so, you'd be able to trace `MyProcedure`'s execution and see what takes that much time.

Apart from that, see whether there are uncommitted (or rolled back) transactions that hold certain rows (tables?) **locked** so - when you called `MyProcedure` - it waits for another session to commit (or roll back) in order to be able to continue its execution.

Comment: I commit obsessively after every query. Yes, this is a stored procedure. But why does it run fine in oracle though? And yes, I will add logging, thank you!

Comment: Without logging, you don't even know whether it (MyProcedure) started or not. Maybe it is waiting somewhere for something. Where/what? I wouldn't know, but I do wish you luck and hope you'll find the culprit. Logging might help, so - you're welcome :)

Comment: Hey, I will mark this as an answer for now. For some weird reason it's now running fine. Yes, totally agree, logging helps and I use it in other projects but didnt even get to write it when it ran after restart. Weird.